# Set a date field with AdjustDay (NotesDateTime Class)

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript, lotus

I have a problem with my code, at the end when the script tries to save de doc lotus show me an error:

> Validation error on format.

I want to change the day reminder and I am trying first in a event buttom and then I would like to implement this code into an agent, is this...

```vb
Sub Click(Source As Button)

'... other variables declared ...

Dim dateTime As NotesDateTime
Dim nuevoRecordatorio As Variant

Set uidoc = ws.CurrentDocument
Set doc = uidoc.Document
Set item = doc.GetFirstItem("TempoFechaRecordatorio01")
Set dateTime = item.DateTimeValue

Messagebox (dateTime.DateOnly)

Call dateTime.AdjustDay(15)

Messagebox (dateTime.DateOnly)

nuevoRecordatorio = dateTime.DateOnly

Messagebox (nuevoRecordatorio)

Set item2 = doc.ReplaceItemValue("TempoFechaRecordatorio01",Cdat(nuevoRecordatorio))

Messagebox (doc.TempoFechaRecordatorio01(0))

Call uidoc.Save
Call uidoc.Close End Sub
```

I have tried without `Cdat(...)`, but the result is the same: `format error`.

Could anyone give me any instruccion to fix this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NotesDateTime.DateOnly` property returns a `string` value, so you need to convert this value to `date` value by using `DateValue` function:

```vb
'Your code.

Set item2 = doc.ReplaceItemValue("TempoFechaRecordatorio01", DateValue(nuevoRecordatorio))

'Your code.
```

Also you can use `date` values directly:

```vb
'Your code.
vDate = doc.GetItemValue("TempoFechaRecordatorio01")(0)

vDate = vDate + 15

doc.ReplaceItemValue("TempoFechaRecordatorio01", Datenumber(Year(vDate), Month(vDate), Day(vDate))
'Your code.
```

In other way you can use `Evaluate` function:

```vb
'Your code.

doc.ReplaceItemValue("TempoFechaRecordatorio01", Evaluate({@Adjust(@Date(TempoFechaRecordatorio01); 0; 0; 15; 0; 0; 0)}, doc)

'Your code.
```

Comment: Thanks @nempoBu4, Error fixed.